# how to show all method in <class 'google.appengine.api.users.User'>

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i want to see the all method in

how to get it

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/users.py#58), <strike>luke</strike> zjm1126 (or [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html)).

Answer (score 3):

As Tamás has answered, you can use the `dir` function, but I think all the methods are well explained in the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html#User_nickname):

> Instance Methods
>
> A User instance provides the following
>   methods:
>
> **nickname()**
>
> Returns the "nickname" of the user, a displayable name. The nickname
>   will be either the "name" portion of
>   the user's email address if the
>   address is in the same domain as the
>   application, or the user's full email
>   address otherwise.
>
> **email()**
>
> Returns the email address of the user. Applications should use nickname
>   for displayable names.
>
> **user_id()**
>
> Returns the unique permanent ID of the user, a str. This ID is always the
>   same for the user regardless of
>   whether the user changes her email
>   address.

Answer (score 1):

```
from google.appengine.api.users import User
print dir(User)
```